# cv2.VideoWriter() doesn't seem to output anything with 'H264' codec, works perfectly for 'mp4v'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, google-colaboratory

I've been working on saving a video using `cv2.VideoWriter()` class on google colab, but what I have been facing is that it doesn't output anything if codec is set to 'h264' but works fine for 'mp4v' codec. I've tried different versions of OpenCV but didn't meet any luck. Any solution to this problem?